# Using $ in vscode snippets

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, sass, vscode-snippets

I am trying to create a snippet which includes a $ sign, but in output vscode is skipping the $ sign and making the text selected.

```
"Color 1": {
        "prefix": "c1",
        "body": [
            "color: $c1;"
        ]
    }
```

**Output**

```
color: c1;
```

I have also tried using \ and ''. Can anyone please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape `$` sign in snippets with double backslash `\\` like this:

```
"Color 1": {
    "prefix": "c1",
    "body": [
            "color: \\$c1;"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Snippet Doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_how-do-i-have-a-snippet-place-a-variable-in-the-pasted-script) page

---

#### How do I have a snippet place a variable in the pasted script?

To have a variable in the pasted script, you need to escape the `'$'` of the $variable name so that it isn't parsed by the snippet expansion phase.

```
"VariableSnippet":{
    "prefix": "_Var",
    "body": "\\$MyVar = 2",
    "description": "A basic snippet that places a variable into script with the $ prefix"
  }
```

This results in the pasted snippet as:

```
$MyVar = 2
```